# How do i change the logging in runtime in ActiveMQ Artemis broker

Tags: activemq-artemis

In case of any network issues or during triage some other issue, I would like to enable logging in the ActiveMQ Artemis broker (2.6.1) without restarting the broker to get more logging.

Currently I'm restarting the broker after enabling/disabling logging in logging.properties

```
logger.level=DEBUG
```

In ActiveMQ 5.x there is a JMX operation exposed (as mentioned in https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-change-the-logging). I couldn't find similar one for Artemis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of ActiveMQ Artemis you're using doesn't support reloading logging configuration at runtime. This functionality was implemented via [ARTEMIS-2121](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2121) so you'll need to move to 2.6.4 or 2.7.0 to get it.

Once you update your `logging.properties` the broker will reload it and a message will be logged that the logging configuration was reloaded. By default it may take up to 5 seconds to reload (based on the `configuration-file-refresh-period` in broker.xml which defaults to `5000` milliseconds).